# Getting sequence of time HH:MM:SS without using date

Tags: r, datetime, time, time-series

I want to get a time sequence without using dates in R. I googled it but didn't find anything . I have one approach of doing this but that is too with dates.

```
a <- seq(from=as.POSIXct("2012-01-01 00:00:00", tz="UTC"), 
    to=as.POSIXct("2012-01-01 05:00:00", tz="UTC"), by="hour")


a <- strftime(a, format="%H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")
a <- times(a) 
a
 [1] 00:00:00 01:00:00 02:00:00 03:00:00 04:00:00 05:00:00
```

I just want to know is there exist any approach that produce a time sequence (w/o using dates)

Comment: What's wrong with using dates?

Comment: @nrussell nothing . Just wanted a cleaner way to do the things. If there exist a method without dates then code will be much shorter

Comment: Maybe, maybe not though?

Answer (score 2):

The `"times"` class of chron can represent times below `24:00:00` without dates:

```
library(chron)

times(0:5/24)
## [1] 00:00:00 01:00:00 02:00:00 03:00:00 04:00:00 05:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
substr(as.character(a),12,19)
```

OR

```
sapply(strsplit(as.character(a)," "), "[[", 2)
```